# 'Intent Filter Verification Service has Stopped' while running appium tests on Saucelab

Tags: appium, saucelabs

So we have written our tests in Appium-JAVA which are running fine locally on our device but the following error is encountered while running on Saucelabs -

[image: screenshot]

What is it and how to resolve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone interested, we migrated to browserstack and we didn't face this issue there.

Comment: Have you found solution for this

Comment: @MukeshkumarS no we migrated to browserstack